# How to analyze non-linear unbalanced yearly data

Tags: panel-data, nonlinear-regression

I need advice regarding an analysis I wish to perform. I have 10 data files, each represents a different year (2003-2012). Each file, contains a filed of family ID, and a field of Subject ID within the family ID. In addition, I have a variable of interest: the monthly income, and explanatory variables, from which the one of main interest is the age. I wish to find:
1. The relationships between income and age (which theoretically is expected to be quadratic).
2. The change of this relationship over the years.
I need your advice on which model I need for answering these two questions. But it ain't as simple as that. Most families has only 1 subject. A few has 2, and only a minority has more. In addition, a minority of the families (and subjects) appear on more than one file (year), while no subject appears on all 10 files, and there are many families and subjects that appears on 1 file only (data is messy!). From numbers point of view, each file contains around 10,000 subjects, which is good and bad. While modeling, I need to be very careful, and produce more than just a P-Value, since I expect P-Values to be low just due to the small sample size. I am attaching a sketch of the table for one representative year, and a plot of income vs. age in this year, not taking into account the family. There are many families and I am afraid of estimating too many parameters. Do you think it's possible to model each year separately and somehow compare the coefficients?
Thank you!
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to answer this, maybe you could ask more explicit questions.

For sure you first need to transform this data so that all data on a family is merged in one row. So you need to create some aggregation. You cannot keep a 'gender' attribute for example. Maybe you want attributes like: number adults, number children, marital status, sum education years, average adult age, ...

Then you can create linear regression models to model the relation age -> income

Once you have done this I suggest to create a plot of this relation over the years to answer your second question.

Comment: I am not sure. Your suggestion is taking me away from my question of interest, which is the relationship between age and income, not the average age in a family and the average income in a family. Is this the only option? Can't I used some panel structure, with random effects?